# Looking for story with black buildings that reflect no light

Tags: story-identification

I am thinking 70s. I read it in th early 80s. It is set in the nearish future with extreme income inequality. The buildings of the rich are arcologies and don't reflect light because of highly efficient solar panels.

It is a short story possibly in an anthology.

Young male protagonist (like that is going to help) bastard son of a rich father. He ends up being killed. It might be a translation.

Comment: You're thinking the story was from the 1970's or is that when you read it?

Comment: I tried googling. They apparently might exist is reality soon. (The buildings) http://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/small_1x_/public/screen_shot_2015-03-16_at_2.04.21_pm.png?itok=ohyzmZ61